# Macro code written is not giving me expected result

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a third sheet which takes column from sheet 1 and sheet 2 and then create a master sheet based on column values in first two sheets

I have tried to write a macro but it is not giving me expected result. Below is my macro code

```
Sub OneCell()

Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(1)
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(2)
Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(3).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(3)
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(3).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(4)
Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(5)

End Sub
```

**Sample Data in Sheet 1:**

```
First Name  Last Name   Age Postal Code

 1. Alex    Greenewood  23  B3M3N4
 2. Almira  Hassan      24  T5R4Y6
 3. Anthony Conwood     25  L4L4L4
 4. Charlie Spectar     23  H4H4H4
 5. Capilar Ross        24  U2U3U3
 6. Meera   Yu          25  S7S7S7
 7. Nancy   Ohak        23  E6E6E6
 8. Ahmed   Mu          24  Q4Q4Q4
 9. Derek   Tiz         25  P0P0P0
```

**Sample Data in Sheet 2:**

```
First Name  Status  Company Town

1. Alex     Single  XYZ     Halifax
2. Almira   Married UTY     Calgary
3. Anthony  Single  XYZ     Vancouver
4. Charlie  Single  YTR     Delta
5. Alvy     Married YYZ     Kitchener
6. Ero      Married YYC     Waterloo
7. Capilar  Married UOI     Kitchener
8. Meera    Single  RTD     Bedford
9. Nari     Single  HHH     Waterloo
10. Nancy   Single  OTY     Bedford
11. Vicky   Married ERT     Halifax
12. Ahmed   Single  INY     Kitchener
13. Derek   Single  AYQ     Kitchener
```

**Expected Result:**
If sheet 1 and sheet 2 has common first name columns data related to that row should print first. If Sheet 1 has extra first name which is not in Sheet 2, rows related to that should print at the end in Sheet 3 and same in the case if Sheet 2 has extra first names which are not present in Sheet 1, should print data related to that names at the end in Sheet 3 after the common first name has been captured.

```
First Name  Last Name   Company Age Status

 1. Alex    Greenewood  XYZ     23  Single
 2. Almira  Hassan      UTY     24  Married 
 4. Anthony Conwood     XYZ     25  Single
 5. Charlie Spectar     YTR     23  Single
 6. Capilar Ross        UOI     24  Married
 7. Meera   Yu          RTD     25  Single
 8. Nancy   Ohak        OTY     23  Single
 9. Ahmed   Mu          INY     24  Single
 10. Derek  Tiz         AYQ     25  Single
 11. Alvy               YYZ         Married
 12. Ero                YYC         Married
 13. Nari               HHH         Single
 14. Vicky              ERT         Married
```

But based on current macro the output is not coming as expected and it is giving me mismatched data in rows after first uncommon name comes up in Sheet 2

Comment: An: recommend you try recording the macro first then edit. Works much better.

Comment: Your code is a straight copy/paste. You need to add logic to it - what have you tried?

Comment: The macro does not attempt at matching anything with anything, it's simply doing copy/paste of whole columns from one sheet to another. You will need to add some logic here.

Comment: First, decide which sheet (`Sheet1` or `Sheet2`) is the "master sheet" -- the sheet with **all** the needed names.Second copy the relevant columns from that sheet to `Sheet3`. Third, lookup each value in the other sheet and copy the corresponding data to `Sheet3` (this last could be done with formulas)

Comment: This is likely best solved with a `VLOOKUP` formula.